# Determine the number of subsets

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, binomial-coefficients, combinations, alternative-proof

> How many distinct subsets of a set $\text{A}$ are there, containing at least $9$ elements, where the total number of elements in set $\text{A}$ is $18$ ?

I've solved it by making cases of either choosing $9$, $10$, $11$ and so on elements from the set and then adding them up, i.e, $$\sum_{r=9}^{18} \dbinom{18}{r} $$

However, the answer given in my book is $$\dfrac{1}{2} \times \dfrac{18!}{9! \cdot 9!} + 2^{17}$$

Although the numerical value of my answer and book's answer is equal, I'm interested in knowing the intended solution of the author.

The term $\dfrac{1}{2} \times \dfrac{18!}{9! \cdot 9!}$ is dividing $18$ elements into two equal parts. The term $2^{17}$ is the total number of subsets of a set containing $17$ elements. But I can't connect these two things with the question.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

**P.S.** If anyone is interested in knowing how I found $\displaystyle \sum_{r=9}^{18} \dbinom{18}{r} $ here is my method,

Let $\text{S} = \displaystyle \sum_{r=9}^{18} \dbinom{18}{r} $

By Binomial Theorem,

$2^{18} = (1+1)^{18} = \displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^{18} \dbinom{18}{r} $

$\implies 2\text{S} - \dbinom{18}{9} =2^{18} \left( \because \dbinom{18}{r} = \dbinom{18}{18-r}\right)$

and the rest follows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A$ has $18$ elements, and $B\subseteq A$ has fewer than $9$ elements, then $B^c\subseteq A$ has more than nine elements. Also, if $B$ has more than $9$ elements then $B^c$ has fewer than $9$ elements. That means the number of subsets of $A$ with fewer than $9$ elements equals the number of subsets of $A$ with more than $9$ elements.

Of course, the complement of a set with $9$ elements is another set with $9$ elements. The number you want, the number of subsets of $A$ with at least $9$ elements, is *almost* half the number of all subsets of $A$. We can figure out just how close that *almost* is.

Let $m$ be the number of subsets of $A$ with more than $9$ elements, so $m$ is also the number of subsets of $A$ with fewer than $9$ elements. Let $n$ be the number of subsets of $A$ with exactly $9$ elements. Then you want to find $m+n$, and we can find it from the total number of subsets of $A$, which we'll call $t$.

$$\text{(fewer than $9$)+(exactly $9$)+(more than $9$)=(all)}$$
$$m+n+m=t$$
$$\begin{align}
m+n&=\frac 12n+\frac 12t \\
 &=\frac 12{18 \choose 9}+\frac 12\cdot 2^{18} \\
 &=\frac 12 \cdot \frac{18!}{9! \cdot 9!} + 2^{17}
\end{align}$$

Comment: The answer is as gentle as instructive. +1

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are $2^{18}$  subsets all in all.  Of these, $\dfrac{18!}{9!\cdot 9!}$ have exactly $9$ elements.  The rest either have more than $9$ or fewer than $9$.  Now, by symmetry, the number of subsets with more than $9$ elements equals the number of subsets with fewer than $9$ (pair each subset with its complement).  Thus the number of subsets with more than $9$ elements is $\dfrac{1}{2} \times \left(2^{18} - \dfrac{18!}{9!\cdot 9!}\right)$.  Adding the number of subsets with exactly $9$ elements gives the desired result.